# How to parse various answers from server and Retrofit

Tags: rest, retrofit2

The server can answer like:

```
{ "data1":"value", "data2":"value" }
```

or:

```
{ "error":"text" }
```

or:

```
{ "json":"{ "error":"text" }" }
```

How to parse various answers from the server using retrofit.
Maybe I should make a rich POJO like:

```
class MyAnswer {
   String data1;
   String data2;
   String error;
   // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Google's Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) to Serialize/Deserialize Json strings to POJO's and deserialize back. 
Retrofit2 also supports Gson as a converter.

Add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson'` to your build.gradle and create Retrofit instance like below:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Define your Java classes and annotate them with Gson's `SerializedName` tag.

```
public class MyAnswer {
    @SerializedName("data1")
    public String data1;

    @SerializedName("data2")
    public String data2;

    @SerializedName("error")
    public String error;
}
```

Then you can get your POJO on the onResponse method:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ExampleClass> call, Response<ExampleClass> response) {
    ExampleClass exampleClass = response.body();
    ......
}
```

You can also deserialize yourself from Json:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ExampleClass ec = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ExampleClass.class);
```

Or serialize to Json:

```
ExampleClass ec = new ExampleClass();
ec.data1 = "Some text";
ec.data2 = "Another text";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(ec);
```

You can also create nested/complex structures with Gson. 
For more information, visit [their user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).